# Check if field/ SQL cell contains value in hh:mm:ss if so then split

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, date

I have a ReportViewer and in it field column loaded from SQL Database.

I would like to check with expression or with SQL query if the field/cell contains value in format `hh:mm:ss` if so I would like to delete this string.

E.g. the field might be: `11:30:00, London`

The time and place is every time split by `,`

And if the cell contains that value I would like to display only the Place e.g. `London`

What would be better, to check with expression or in SQL query and could you please help me with this?

The SQL query looks like following: `SELECT event,name,surname, TimeandPlace FROM table1`

Thank you for your time in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get pretty close with:

```
where TimeAndPlace like '%[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]%'
```

A more accurate approach would be:

```
where TimeAndPlace like '%[0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]%' or
      TimeAndPlace like '%[2][0-3]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]%'
```

This is assuming a 24-hour clock.

EDIT:

If you just want the part at the end of the string, use `case`:

```
select (case when TimeAndPlace like '[0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9], %' or
                  TimeAndPlace like '[2][0-3]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9], %'
             then stuff(TimeAndPlace, 1, 10, '')
             else TimeAndPlace
        end)
```

Comment: He want to remove <strong>if so I would like to delete this string.</strong>. He is able to get the value. I think you should suggest him Regex.Replace.

Comment: @Iqbal Thanks for pointing that out but for the Gordon's defence I added that to my question after he posted this answer. Gordon I appreciate your question alot. Thanks

Comment: @Gordon +1 from me. I learned something from your answer otherwise I was thinking different direction.